# MUI x-data-grid gets error: "Cannot find module '../InputBase'"

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

The source snippets are:

```
import React from "./testDetails.css"
import { DataGrid, GridToolbar } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import {PieChart, Pie, Legend, Tooltip, Cell} from "recharts";
import axios from "axios";
import TriageBox from "../../components/triageBox/TriageBox";
```

```
<DataGrid
              rows={data}
              columns={columns}
              pageSize={10}
              rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10]}
              disableSelectionOnClick
              onRowClick={handleRowClick}
              components={{Toolbar: GridToolbar}}
              initialState={{
                filter: {
                  filterModel: {
                    items: [{columnField: 'Result', operator: 'is', value: 'failed'}]
                  }
                }
              }}
          />
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.0",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.119",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.8",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.17.23",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.2.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.6.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "recharts": "^2.2.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

Then it failed to render the page. Error from the console:

```
iconButtonClasses.js:7 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../InputBase'
    at webpackMissingModule (iconButtonClasses.js:7:1)
    at ./node_modules/@mui/material/Input/Input.js (iconButtonClasses.js:7:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./node_modules/@mui/material/TextField/TextField.js (tablePaginationClasses.js:7:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./node_modules/@mui/x-data-grid/constants/defaultGridSlotsComponents.js (GridVirtualScrollerRenderZone.js:47:1)
```

Could any one please advise where can I start to trouble shoot? Thanks!

Tried reinstall the dependencies, and didn't work. Expecting to see page rendered and error gone.

Comment: It says error in iconButtonClasses.js. Can you check there?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it was caused by MUI upgrading. Need to follow https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/migration-v4/ strictly. ThemeProvider should be added in the right place.